# Learning statistics and machine learning

Tags: statistics

I bought the book "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (Hastie, etc.), but struggle with the equations presented. I don't understand how they are derived, there are little explanations to why they are true, the authors only assume that you are on that level. Like this one:

$$EPE(x_0)=E_{y_0|x_0}E_{\mathcal{T}}(y_0-\hat{y_0})^2 = Var(y_0|x_0)+E_{\mathcal{T}}(\hat{y_0}-E_\mathcal{T}\hat{y_0})^2+(E_\mathcal{T}\hat{y_0}-x_0^T\beta)^2$$

My mathematical background are (mainly) calculus, linear algebra and about 20 ECTS statistics, but I don't understand this equation, and while the book is not about mathematical proofs I feel that I must understand the equations to read it. That is, I know the terminology and notation, but not how this equation is derived.

I want to read this book, so perhaps someone have some recommendations? I'm looking for a book or some other resource to make this understandable. I've been through "Modern mathematical statistics with applications" by Berk. I believed that this was enough, but this book from Hastie was a "step up"... because this equation is presented as early as page 26, with no explanation. I'm not on that level.

Comment: There’s no replacement for augmenting reading with pen and paper. Maybe start instead with Chris Bishop’s text.

Comment: Perhaps I could use Hastie's book, but use the internet (and pen and paper!) when there is something that is a level above me. It will take more efforts than on Berk.